# Как переписать данный код в упрощенном формате на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть длинный JS-код (начало и конец обрезаны):

```
}, n.n = function(a) {
        var i = a && a.__esModule ? function() {
            return a.default
        } : function() {
            return a
        };
        return n.d(i, "a", i), i
    }, n.o = function(a, i) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, i)
    }, n.p = "", n(n.s = 3)
}([function(a, i) {
    var n = function() {
        document.body.clientWidth < 479 ? (document.querySelector("body").style.minHeight = "".concat(window.innerHeight, "px"), document.querySelector(".main").style.minHeight = "100%") : (document.querySelector("body").style.minHeight = "100vh", document.querySelector(".main").style.minHeight = "100vh")
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", n), n()
}, function(a, i) {
    if (window.landingConfig.forms) {
        var n = document.querySelector(".email-form__password-input"),
            e = document.querySelector(".email-form__view-icon");
        n && "password" === n.getAttribute("type") && e.classList.add("email-form__view-icon_close"), e.onclick = function() {
            n && "password" === n.getAttribute("type") ? (n.setAttribute("type", "text"), e.classList.add("email-form__view-icon_open"), e.classList.remove("email-form__view-icon_close")) : (n.setAttribute("type", "password"), e.classList.add("email-form__view-icon_close"), e.classList.remove("email-form__view-icon_open"))
        }
    }
}, function(a, i) {
    function n(a, i) {
        for (var n = 0; n < i.length; n++) {
            var e = i[n];
            e.enumerable = e.enumerable || !1, e.configurable = !0, "value" in e && (e.writable = !0), Object.defineProperty(a, e.key, e)
        }
```

Как из этого кода грамотно вычленить только этот код, чтобы он работал? И переписать его на jQuery без сокращенных форматов (без знаков : > ?)?

```
var n = function() {
        document.body.clientWidth < 479 ? (document.querySelector("body").style.minHeight = "".concat(window.innerHeight, "px"), document.querySelector(".main").style.minHeight = "100%") : (document.querySelector("body").style.minHeight = "100vh", document.querySelector(".main").style.minHeight = "100vh")
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", n), n()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что будет работать, но вроде правильно написал.

```js
let n = function () {
    if ($("body").width < 479) {
        let height = $(this).height();
        $(this).css("min-height", height);
        $(".main").css("min-height", 100 + "%");
    } else {
        $(this).css("min-height", 100 + "vh");
        $(".main").css("min-height", 100 + "vh");
    }
};
n();
```